# where is the string operator + source code?

Tags: c#, .net

As I'm checking the following code `string s = "a" + 1` works.

In a tooltip Visual Studio shows that it uses `string operator + (string left, object right)`[image]

Anyway, its not mentioned in the [source code of String](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,705), as there are only `==` and `!=`.

I definitely could assume that it uses something similar to `left + right.ToString()`, but really want to check its real source code.

P.S. Having it is not present in the C# source code multiplies my interest to infinity :)

Comment: The IL shows `call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object, object)`.

Comment: indeed, compiler just replaces string operator + with Concat...

Comment: Cool that you figured it out! Are you going to answer this yourself, or waiting for someone else?

Comment: The source code applies to System.String, but string is a keyword in the C# language.  The compiler knows a lot about built-in types, so much that your project doesn't even have a reference to mscorlib.dll.  Breaking that dependency, later, required the /nostdlib compile option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This is new for me and I'm not a compiler specialist, here's my best shot.*

## Where is the source code?

### Short answer

Throughout [.NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)'s code.

### Longer answer

There are 3 built-in operators in c# for `string`.

```
string operator +(string x, string y);
string operator +(string x, object y);
string operator +(object x, string y);
```

(Reference below)

You can see them in Roslyn's source code in [`BuiltInOperators`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/BuiltInOperators.cs,315) class.

```
(int)BinaryOperatorKind.StringConcatenation,
(int)BinaryOperatorKind.StringAndObjectConcatenation,
(int)BinaryOperatorKind.ObjectAndStringConcatenation,
```

The you can follow the `Kind`s to the [`BinaryOperatorKind`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/Semantics/Operators/OperatorKind.cs,262) enum.

```
StringConcatenation = String | Addition,
StringAndObjectConcatenation = StringAndObject | Addition,
ObjectAndStringConcatenation = ObjectAndString | Addition,
```

The end part (after it has been recognized as an addition expression) of the magic of making `+` into a call to string.Concat seems to happen in [`RewriteStringConcatenation`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Lowering/LocalRewriter/LocalRewriter_StringConcat.cs,24) method.

First the left and the right sides are converted to strings, which may require calling `ToString()` which you can see in the IL posted by others.

```
// Convert both sides to a string (calling ToString if necessary)
loweredLeft = ConvertConcatExprToString(syntax, loweredLeft);
loweredRight = ConvertConcatExprToString(syntax, loweredRight);
```

Many lines after, one of the `RewriteStringConcatenationNNNxprs` methods may be called, for example [`RewriteStringConcatenationTwoExprs`](http://sourceroslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Lowering/LocalRewriter/LocalRewriter_StringConcat.cs,8137fb5945669035) which provides the special `string.Concat` method.

```
private BoundExpression RewriteStringConcatenationTwoExprs(SyntaxNode syntax, BoundExpression loweredLeft, BoundExpression loweredRight)
{
   Debug.Assert(loweredLeft.HasAnyErrors || loweredLeft.Type.IsStringType());
   Debug.Assert(loweredRight.HasAnyErrors || loweredRight.Type.IsStringType());

   var method = UnsafeGetSpecialTypeMethod(syntax, SpecialMember.System_String__ConcatStringString);
   Debug.Assert((object)method != null);

   return (BoundExpression)BoundCall.Synthesized(syntax, null, method, loweredLeft, loweredRight);
}
```

## References for string operators

The following is from *Addition operator* section of [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#addition-operator) article which is part of C# specification.

> - String concatenation:
>
> ```
> string operator +(string x, string y);
> string operator +(string x, object y);
> string operator +(object x, string y);
> ```
>
> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted. Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object. If ToString returns null, an empty string is substituted.
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> class Test
> {
>     static void Main() {
>         string s = null;
>         Console.WriteLine("s = >" + s + "<");        // displays s = ><
>         int i = 1;
>         Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);               // displays i = 1
>         float f = 1.2300E+15F;
>         Console.WriteLine("f = " + f);               // displays f = 1.23E+15
>         decimal d = 2.900m;
>         Console.WriteLine("d = " + d);               // displays d = 2.900
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The result of the string concatenation operator is a string that consists of the characters of the left operand followed by the characters of the right operand. The string concatenation operator never returns a null value. A System.OutOfMemoryException may be thrown if there is not enough memory available to allocate the resulting string.

---

The source code for .NET 4.8 for string is at [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,705) but it only contains sources for `operator ==` and `operator !=`.

## Syntax Visualiser

You may or may not find this relevant to this question, but Visual Studio comes with Syntax Visualiser (View -> Other Windows) which provides a window to some of the magic of code generation.

[image]

Comment: You're awesome!

Answer (score 3):

I thought that it call ToString() and String.Concat(string , string)

C#

```
   object aa = 123;
   String a = "123" + aa;
```

IL

```
.method public hidebysig 
        instance void DoSomeMoreStuff () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 33 (0x21)
        .maxstack 2
        .locals init (
            [0] object,
            [1] string
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 123
        IL_0003: box [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32
        IL_0008: stloc.0
        IL_0009: ldstr "123"
        IL_000e: ldloc.0
        IL_000f: brtrue.s IL_0014

        IL_0011: ldnull
        IL_0012: br.s IL_001a

        IL_0014: ldloc.0
        IL_0015: callvirt instance string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object::ToString()

        IL_001a: call string [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String::Concat(string, string)
        IL_001f: stloc.1
        IL_0020: ret
    } // end of method SomeClass::DoSomeMoreStuff
```

Answer (score 2):

It's built into the C# specification.  That is why the tooltip show the information it shows, and no additional source code is needed.

Excerpt from Microsoft Doc: [+ and += operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator)

> The + and += operators are supported by the built-in integral and floating-point numeric types, the string type, and delegate types.

[C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) is standardized by ECMA International as the ECMA-334 standard and by ISO/IEC as the ISO/IEC 23270 standard. The latest ISO standard [ISO/IEC 23270:2018](https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c075178_ISO_IEC_23270_2018.zip) is available can be downloaded from https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c075178_ISO_IEC_23270_2018.zip

Excerpt From ISO:

> **12.9.5 Addition operator** For an operation of the form x + y, binary operator overload resolution (§12.4.5) is applied to select a
>   specific operator implementation. The operands are converted to the parameter types of the selected
>   operator, and the type of the result is the return type of the operator
>
> **12.4.5 Binary operator overload resolution**
>   An operation of the form x op y, where op is an overloadable binary operator, x is an expression of type X,
>   and y is an expression of type Y, is processed as follows:

This list of public available standards listed here: https://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html